# MySQL Query Inserts Default Data instead of Input Data

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment

I'm currently writing a web application for the private home loan sector. In this application, Loan Terms are created between a borrower, an originator, and a funding source, so that when they apply for a loan, they can choose the terms that match their needs best...

I'm using MySQL 5.4. The table has three foreign keys (borrowerId,originatorId,fundingSourceId). Existing rows can be updated, but my insert command is not inserting its data, only a new row with the table's default values. The table's format is as follows...

```
id                  int(11)    NOTNULL,PRIMARY,AUTO_INCREMENT
borrowerId          int(11)    NOTNULL,DEFAULT 0
originatorId        int(11)    NOTNULL,DEFAULT 0
fundingSourceId     int(11)    NOTNULL,DEFAULT 0
originatorFee       dec(10,2)  NOTNULL
fundingSourceFee    dec(10,2)  NOTNULL
interestRate        dec(5,3)   NOTNULL
penaltyRate         dec(5,3)   NOTNULL
loanDuration        int(11)    NOTNULL,DEFAULT 0
minimumInterestDays int(11)    NOTNULL,DEFAULT 0
disabled            tinyint(1) NOTNULL,DEFAULT 0
createdAt           datetime   NOTNULL
updatedAt           datetime   NULL
deletedAt           datetime   NULL
```

Here is my Insert command that is producing a row with zeroes across the board, instead of the data I enter (including Created At as 0000-00-00 00:00:00)

```
INSERT INTO loanterms
(borrowerId,originatorId,originatorFee,fundingSourceId,fundingSourceFee,
interestRate,penaltyRate,loanDuration,minimumInterestDays,disabled,createdAt)
VALUES (borrowerId = 64, originatorId = 3, originatorFee = 300.00, 
fundingSourceId = 11, fundingSourceFee = 300.00, interestRate = 15.00, 
penaltyRate = 20.00, loanDuration = 6, minimumInterestDays = 30, disabled = 0,
createdAt = now())
```

EDIT: The following query produces a row that contains all data properly... I had to insert the ID auto incrementing field into the query. Does this mean there is a problem with my auto-increment? How can I fix it?

```
INSERT INTO loanterms VALUES (124, 64, 3, 11, 300.00, 300.00, 15.00, 20.00, 6, 
30, 0, now(), NULL, NULL)
```

EDIT 2: Well thank you all for pointing out my stupid mistake... Sorry it took me a few minutes to realize it. This was a midnight query and I still haven't had my coffee yet today...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL:

**Change**:

```
INSERT INTO loanterms
(borrowerId,originatorId,originatorFee,fundingSourceId,fundingSourceFee,
interestRate,penaltyRate,loanDuration,minimumInterestDays,disabled,createdAt)
VALUES (borrowerId = 64, originatorId = 3, originatorFee = 300.00, 
fundingSourceId = 11, fundingSourceFee = 300.00, interestRate = 15.00, 
penaltyRate = 20.00, loanDuration = 6, minimumInterestDays = 30, disabled = 0,
createdAt = now())
```

**To**:

```
INSERT INTO loanterms
set borrowerId = 64, 
    originatorId = 3, 
    originatorFee = 300.00, 
    fundingSourceId = 11, 
    fundingSourceFee = 300.00, 
    interestRate = 15.00, 
    penaltyRate = 20.00, 
    loanDuration = 6, 
    minimumInterestDays = 30, 
    disabled = 0,
    createdAt = now();
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. What is wrong with my syntax? Is INSERT () VALUES () only an MsSQL syntax? I've never had trouble using it with MySQL before...

Comment: No. `insert into table ( col, names, .. ) values( val1, val2, .. )` is the generic syntax. What you tried was `MySQL` specific.

Comment: Ok I'm just full retard... I didn't even realize what I had done until just now.

Comment: Yes. When used with `values`, the statements like `borrowerId = 64`, `originatorId = 3`, etc become logical expressions returning a `true` or `false`. As the comparisons returned a `false`, its numeric equivalent `0` was replaced and hence inserted the same into the table.

Comment: Thank you, that's entirely logical. I did not even realize that I had placed the columns in the query twice. I had copied the query from a previous one that was an UPDATE instead of an INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add all the columns again, in you Values, remove all the column names, like this:

```
VALUES (64,3,300.00, 11,300.00, 15.00, 20.00, 6,30,0,now())
```

just make sure the order of the value correspond to the order of the columns

Comment: The reason I am using the INSERT (...) VALUES (...) format is because it makes it easier to work with in my Scripting Language. There are also updatedAt and deletedAt fields within the table that I am not setting values for.

In any case, I've tested your query revised as VALUES (64,3,11,300.00,300.00, 15.00, 20.00, 6,30,0,now(), NULL, NULL) and receive a Column Count does not Match Row Count error. Perhaps there is a problem with my AUTO_INCREMENT somehow?

Comment: yes, but you only need to remove the column names from VALUES (), like this:

`INSERT INTO loanterms
(borrowerId,originatorId,originatorFee,fundingSourceId,fundingSourceFee,
interestRate,penaltyRate,loanDuration,minimumInterestDays,disabled,createdAt) VALUES (64,3,300.00, 11,300.00, 15.00, 20.00, 6,30,0,now())`

Comment: Right, but what is WRONG with that syntax? I've used that syntax hundreds of times with no problem until today.